# Gap in Maclachlan/Reid's Proof of Bass's Theorem in Hyperbolic Geometry: Closedness?

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

I am reading *MacLachlan / Reid: The Arithmetic of Hyperbolic 3-Manifolds*.

**Bass's Theorem** (Thm. 5.2.2) states that a finite volume hyperbolic 3-manifold $M = H^3 / \Gamma$, with $\Gamma \subset SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ discrete, that has non-integral trace (i. e. $\mathrm{tr}\, g$ is not an algebraic integer for some $g \in \Gamma$) contains a closed embedded essential surface.

#### Definitions

The book does not give a definition of *essentiality* but I believe it is defined as in *Cooper / Long / Reid: Essential Closed Surfaces in Bounded 3-Manifolds*, Introduction: an embedding $i: S \to M$ of a closed, orientable connected surface $S$ is called **essential** if $\pi_1 i: \pi_1 S \to \pi_1 M$ is injective and $(\pi_1 i)(\pi_1 S)$ cannot be conjugated into a subgroup $\pi_1 (\partial_0 M)$ of $\pi_1 M$ where $\partial_0 M$ is a component of $\partial M$.

In section 1.5.1, **embeddings** $f: S \to M$ are defined to require $f(\partial S) \subseteq \partial M$. An embedded surface $f: S \to M$ is called **compressible** if $S$ is a 2-sphere and $f(S)$ bounds a 3-ball in $M$ or if $\pi_1 f: \pi_1 S \to\pi_1 M$ is not injective. Otherwise it is called **incompressible**.

#### The proof

In sections 5.2.1 and 5.2.2, the authors give a proof which I am able to follow up to the point where the existence of an embedded incompressible surface which is not boundary-parallel is deduced.

In the last sentence (p. 170) the proof then goes on to state that according to Thm. 1.5.3 , the surface can also be chosen to be closed. Closedness is neither mentioned in the formulation of this theorem (nor anything I can connect to it) nor in its sibling Thm. 1.5.2:

Leaving out the assumptions of Thm. 1.5.2 and 1.5.3 which are conditions on the algebraic structure of the fundamental group, the theorems say

> Then $M$ contains an embedded incompressible surface that is not
> boundary parallel. (Thm. 1.5.2)

and

> Then $M$ contains an embedded incompressible surface. Furthermore if
> $C$ is a connected subset of $\partial M$ for which the image of
> $\pi_1 C$ in $\pi_1 M$ is contained in a vertex stabilizer, then the
> surface may be taken disjoint from $C$. (Thm. 1.5.3)

respectively. The term "vertex stabilizer" is to be understood in the context of Bass-Serre Theory again (with $\pi_1 M$ acting on the tree of $SL(2, K_P)$, see section 5.2.1).

*Do you have an idea how to fill this gap?*

You could try to simply take the closure of the surface within $M$, but the problem is that a cusped hyperbolic manifold $M$ will only be the interior of a compact manifold with torus boundary components. Thm. 1.5.3 ensures that the surface can be taken disjoint from a boundary component, but I do not see why this extends to the closure of the surface.

(I am also tagging `group-theory` in case this is a consequence of the Bass-Serre theory involved in the proof.)

**Related questions** discussing the intended application of Bass's Theorem:

- [Do once-punctured torus bundles have integral traces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4237616/478924)
- https://mathoverflow.net/q/403048/129446

Comment: What *does* Theorem 1.5.3 say?

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the suggestion, I have added the statements.

Comment: One other question: How is "embedded incompressible surface" defined? In particular, what conditions does that definition impose on the boundary of the surface?

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you, I have included the definitions from the book.

Comment: Let me accompany my answer with one more extended comment. You wrote "... I do not see why this extends to the closure of the surface". I worry here that there is some confusion between the two uses of "closed": (1) for a manifold such as a surface to be "closed" means that $S$ is compact its boundary is empty; (2) for a subset of a topological space to be "closed" means that its complement is open.

Comment: In the context of your post and the papers you quote from, $M$ should be regarded as a compact manifold with boundary (except for Bass' Theorem, where $M$ is the *interior* of a compact manifold whose boundary is a union of toruses). Also, $S$ is *always* closed in sense (2), and therefore compact. Hence the issue is whether $S$ is closed in sense (1), i.e. whether $\partial S = \emptyset$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for your answer. But it is the closedness in sense (2) / compactness that I do not understand. Once-punctured torus bundles, for instance, have by definition an HNN-extension as fundamental group, so according to Thm. 1.5.2 they contain an incompressible embedded surface that is not boundary parallel. But this surface is simply the fiber, a once-punctured torus and hence non-compact.

Comment: An end compactification of such a bundle would add one point at its cusp, a "fiberwise" compactification would add an $S^1$ and the compactification we work with here adds a boundary torus. But in all cases the once-punctured torus is disjoint from the added points, but its closure inside the compactification is not.

Comment: As I indicated in my previous comment, in setting of Theorem 1.5.2 the cusp has been cut off, leaving a compact 3-manifold with torus boundary which fibers over the circle, and the fiber is a *one-holed* torus with circle boundary which is compact (rather than a *once-punctured* torus which is not compact).

Comment: Regarding compactifications, in the setting of Bass theorem where the 3-manifold is noncompact, one usually thinks not about the end compactification but instead about the compactification which adds a torus at infinity, making the given manifold the interior of a compact manifold with torus boundary. The result of adding that torus at infinity is, up to isotopy, identical to cutting off the cusp leaving a compact manifold with torus boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an embedded incompressible surface $S$ in $M$, the requirement that $\partial S$ be embedded in $\partial M$ can be coupled with conclusion of Theorem 1.5.3 which gives conditions on a component $C$ of $\partial M$ which ensure that $S$ is disjoint from that component. The condition says that the image of $\pi_1 C$ in $\pi_1 M$ is contained in a vertex stabilizer.

So, suppose we know the following two properties:

1. For every component $C$ of $\partial M$, the image of $\pi_1 C$ in $\pi_1 M$ is contained in a vertex stabilizer.
2. $S \hookrightarrow M$ is an embedded incompressible surface satisfying the conclusions of Theorem 1.5.3.

It follows that $S$ is disjoint from every component of $\partial M$, and therefore $\partial S \subset S \cap \partial M = \emptyset$. Therefore we may conclude that $S$ is closed. Of course, you have to check that property 1 is actually true in order to reach that conclusion.